# Price Range Layered Navigation inside Quick Search (enable it)

Tags: magento, layered-navigation

there is an option to "Apply Layered Navigation to Quick Search if Search Results are Less Than", and if you put 0, it will appear for all search results.  However, when I do this and do a search in quick search, the price range layered navigation doesn't appear.

When I use the category layered navigation, the price range filters show up.

Is there a way to enable this inside the Admin Panel?  Thanks.

Comment: hmm for some reason i cannot add this question to the tag "magento-admin"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appearance of filters in layered navigation depends on setting for that attribute.
When you edit a attribute from  Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attribte, then you can see that under "Frontend Properties" there is a field "Use In Layered Navigation" with options

```
1. No=> Do not use in layered navigation
2. Filterable (with results) => display in layered navigation only if results are greater than 0(thats what you looking for)
3. Filterable (No results) => always display in layered navigation
```

And to display filter on search result page set "Use In Search Results Layered Navigation" field to yes

Comment: hmm..i can't find the price range attribute, where is that?

Comment: you can do further customization here in Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Price

Comment: you were right that it is in the Manage Attribute but its under another setting "Use In Search Results Layered Navigation" and select Yes. If you update your answer I will mark it as correct.  Thanks.

Comment: thanks, you are right my answer were just for category page not search result page.

Comment: What if you want it to appear on search results but not in category layered navigation?

Comment: set "Use In Layered Navigation" to NO and "Use In Search Results Layered Navigation" to YES

Comment: Oops, it worked! I didn't see it at first because it was at first position and I expected it at the last position.